# How much higher compared to average

Tags: sql

I have a homework assignment asking the following:

**Part 1:** Which Employee has the highest salary? 
I came up with the following code for this part:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Name
    , Salary AS HighestSalary
FROM dbo.ChicagoSalary
ORDER BY HighestSalary DESC;
```

**Part 2:** How Much higher is that person's salary compared to the AVG salary of the department they belong to?

I am completely lost on this part. The instructor stated we can use multiple queries to answer this question.

Any suggestions/hints would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Write a query that generates the average salary, and then tie that into a query that lists each individual's salary.

Comment: select max(salary)-avg(salary) from dbo.ChicagoSalary;

Comment: Are there departments in ChicagoSalary? Or is that the department?

Comment: Great question, @SQLChao.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014

Comment: ChicagoSalary is the table which has columns: Name, PositionTitle, Department, Salary.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you need by using a `CROSS JOIN` with a query that calculates the average salary:

Calculate average salary:

```
SELECT AVG(Salary) Average
  FROM ChicagoSalary
```

Entire query would be something like:

```
SELECT Name, Salary, A.Average
  FROM ChicagoSalary CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT AVG(Salary) Average
  FROM ChicagoSalary) A
```